# Bookshelf js fetch withRelated option returns empty relation object

Tags: javascript, node.js, eager-loading, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have an image model and a location model. The image model contains foreign key to location. To fetch the result I use:

```
fetch({withRelated: ['location']};
```

and i recieve the following results:

```
{
        "id": 24,
        "created_by": 1,
        "location_id": 202,
        "location": {}
}
```

But I want something like:

```
{
        "id": 24,
        "created_by": 1,
        "location": {....}
}
```

My image model:

```
objectProperties = {
    tableName: 'images',
    location: function () {
        return this.hasOne(location, 'id');
    }
};

classProperties = {};

imageModel = bookshelf.Model.extend(objectProperties, classProperties);
```

and my location model:

```
objectProperties = {
    tableName: 'locations',
    images: function () {
        return this.belongsToMany(image, 'location_id');
    }
};

classProperties = {};

locationModel = bookshelf.Model.extend(objectProperties, classProperties);
```

Why do I receive an empty location object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relations in models are wrong. You use belongsToMany (used for m:n relationships only) in combination with hasOne (cannot be used with belongsToMany). It is not clear from your question what kind of relationship do these two tables have so i cannot assist you further. But the problem is not in withRelated but in model definition. Hope this helps.

Comment: An image has one location, but a location may belong to many images. In other words a one-to-many relationship. What is the correct relation to use in each model?

Comment: From the docs: The belongsTo relationship is used when a model is a member of another Target model. It can be used in a one-to-one associations as the inverse of a hasOne. It can also used in one-to-many associations as the inverse of a hasMany (and is the one side of that association).

Comment: It worked! I changed the image model relation to `return this.belongsTo(location);` and location model relation to `return this.hasMany(image, 'location_id');` Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4):

look at the following example

---

person: id_person, name, id_country **withRelated** country: id_country, name, id_province **and withRelated** province: id_province, name

OK generate models person, country and province

person.js

```
'use strict'
const Bookshelf = require('../commons/bookshelf');
const Country   = require('./country');
let Person = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'person',
    idAttribute: 'id_person',
    country: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Country, 'id_country');
    }
});
module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Person', Person);
```

country.js

```
'use strict'
const Bookshelf = require('../commons/bookshelf');
const Province  = require('./province');
let Country = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'country',
    idAttribute: 'id_country',
    province: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Province, 'id_province');
    }
});
module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Country', Country);
```

province.js

```
'use strict'
const Bookshelf = require('../commons/bookshelf');
let Province = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'province',
    idAttribute: 'id_province'
});
module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Province', Province);
```

with collections person.js

```
'use strict'
const Bookshelf = require('../commons/bookshelf');
const Person = require('../models/person');
const Persons = Bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});
module.exports = Persons;
```

with controller person.js

```
'use strict';
const Persons   = require('../collections/persons');
const Person    = require('../models/person');
function getPersons(req, res, next) {
    Motivos.query({})
    .fetch({
        withRelated: [
             'country',
             'country.province'
        ] })
    .then(function(data) {
        return res.status(200).json({
            error: false,
            data: data
        });
    });
}
```

the json is

```
{
    "error":false,
    "data":[{
          "id_person": 1,
          "name": "leonardo",
          "id_country": 3,
          "country":{
                 "id_country": 3,
                 "name":"venezuela",
                 "id_province": 2,
                 "province":{
                        "id_province": 2,
                        "name":"lara"
                 }
           }
    },{...}]
}
```